# Shinyapps pdf not displaying on screen in iframe

Tags: html, r, pdf, iframe, shiny

I am trying to get a pdf to display on screen. The source of the pdf is specified by two user inputs, input$folder and input$report. I am trying to concatenate them together to make the source for an iframe but I keep running into problems. Below is my code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  headerPanel("Client"),

  selectInput("folder", "Select the report type", 
              c(dir("Reports/"))),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.folder == 'Invoice Analysis'",
    selectInput("report", "Choose the PDF",
                          choices = dir("Reports/Invoice Analysis"))),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.folder == 'Pole Attachments'",
    selectInput("report", "Choose the PDF",
                          choices = dir("Reports/Pole Attachments"))),

  htmlOutput("pdfviewer")

)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$pdfviewer <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(src=(paste0("Reports/", input$folder, "/", input$report)), height=300, width=600)
  })



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I run the app it displays the error NOT FOUND in the iframe like this:

[image: error picture]

I have tested to see if the file is actually recognized by running this code

```
file.exists(paste0("Reports/", input$folder, "/", input$report))
```

and it returns true meaning that my file can be found by the pasting of the inputs. I am also not running the code in the viewer, I'm running it in the window and browser to test so I know its not a viewer not displaying pdfs issue. Why can I verify that the file exists but not find it when I try to display it in an iframe?

Comment: Got to make sure your .pdfs are in the same folder as the app. Cannot access the files if the files are stored in a different folder than the shiny app folder, especially if you publish to web. Meaning `Reports` has to be saved in the shiny app folder

Comment: You're setting a `src=` attribute on an iframe that the browser will try to look up. This is not the same as a path where the server can see the file. If you want your shiny server to also serve up static PDF files, take a look at [addResourcePath](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/addResourcePath.html)

Comment: The folder hierarchy is all inside of the folder for the app. My app folder has my app and a folder called Reports. ex. pdfview/(app.r and Reports are both here). Then I have pdfview/Reports/(Invoice Analysis and Pole Attachments are both here).